# generate_series insertar varios datos como serialnumber en SQL server management

Tags: sql-server, tsql, sql-server-management

estoy practicando la funcion generate_series(). Pregunta: como podria ingresar un conjunto de datos de tipo serial en una tabla? Ej: AIBR1000 a AIBR1200

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon lo que has intentado para que se te pueda ayudar

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Para generar esa serie simplemente haces:

```
SELECT concat('AIBR', value)
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1000, 1200) 
--              desde ┘      └ hasta
```

Luego para insertar en una tabla:

```
INSERT INTO Tabla_nombre(columna_nombre)
SELECT concat('AIBR', value)
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1000, 1200)
```

Answer (score 0):

disculpen si no fui claro, pero estuve tratando de resolverlo por mi cuenta y cree un procedure que al ejecutarse pide el rango de datos a insertar que a partir de un dato existente genera el nuevo serial. Sin embargo fue necesario crear mi funcion generated_series() segun este blog https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7347/sql-server-2022-generateseries-function/ de ahi en adelante fue solo armar mi frankenstein.

Este es mi resultado final:

```
        USE database
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[RegisterNewSerial]    Script Date: 26/01/2024 07:56:13 a. m. ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[RegisterNewSerial]
(
@CantidadDeRegistros int,
@Employee varchar(20)
)

as 
begin

set identity_insert DB.dbo.R on

declare @IDRStart int,
@IDRStop int,
@IDCStart int,
@IDCStop int,
@Prefijo varchar(10),
@IDOpe int

set @Prefijo = (select top 1 (SUBSTRING(C,0,6)) from R order by IDR desc)
set @IDRStart = (select top 1 idr from R order by IDR desc)+1
set @IDRStop = (select top 1 idr from R order by IDR desc)+@CantidadDeRegistros
set @IDCStart = (select top 1 (SUBSTRING(C,5,6)*1)+1 from R order by IDR desc)
set @IDCStop = (select top 1 (SUBSTRING(C,5,6)*1) from R order by IDR desc) + @CantidadDeRegistros
set @IDOpe = (select top 1 IDOpe from OtraDB.DBO.Ope where Cod = @Employee)


if exists (select @IDOpe from OtraDB.DBO.Ope)
begin

create table #IDRTable (ID int identity, IdR int)
insert into #IDRTable(IDR)
select value from generate_series(@IDRStart,@IDRStop)

create table #CTable (ID int identity, Code varchar(10))
insert into #CTable(Code)
select value from generate_series(@IDCStart,@IDCStop)

create table #Variables (IDR int, Code varchar(10), LastDate datetime, Activo bit, CreateDate datetime, IDOpe int)
insert into #Variables (IDR,Code,LastDate,Activo,CreateDate,IDOpe)
select IDR,Code,getdate(),1,getdate(),@IDOpe from #IDRTable as I inner join #CodeTable as C on I.ID = C.ID

insert into R(IDR,Code,LastDate,Activo,CreateDate,IdOpe)
select IDR,
@Prefijo+Code,GETDATE(),1,GETDATE(),@IDOpe 
from #Variables

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) LIKE 'dbo' AND name like '#IDRTable')  
   begin
   DROP TABLE [dbo].[#IDRTable]
   end
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) LIKE 'dbo' AND name like '#CTable')  
   begin
   DROP TABLE [dbo].[#CTable]
   end
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) LIKE 'dbo' AND name like '#Variables')  
   begin
   DROP TABLE [dbo].[#Variables]
   end

   set identity_insert DB.dbo.R OFF

end
end
```